Memory not released when using Dictionarys in 64-bit Excel
When I store data in a dictionary, the memory is not released after it goes out of scope or is set to Nothing. I have to explicitly use the RemoveAll method to release the memory.
This problem occurs exclusively with Office 365 64-bit and not with the previously used 32-bit version.
For Example:
Public Sub testDict()
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set dict = New Dictionary
    
    For i = 1 To 100000
        dict.Add i, Format(i, "0000000000")
    Next
    
    dict.RemoveAll
    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub

If dict.RemoveAll is not used in this example, the memory will not be released after the Sub is finished. Every new execution of this Sub will use new memory.
Releasing the memory with the RemoveAll method will not work for nested dictionarys.
For Example:
Public Sub testNestedDict()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    
    Set dict = New Dictionary
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        dict.Add i, New Dictionary
    
        For j = 1 To 10
            dict(i).Add j, New Dictionary
        
            For k = 1 To 10
                dict(i)(j).Add k, New Dictionary
            Next
        Next
    Next
    
    dict.RemoveAll
    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub

In this case every execution will eat up about ~10MB of memory.
I even tried to build a function which erases the dictionary recursively.
Public Sub testNestedDict()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    
    Set dict = New Dictionary
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        dict.Add i, New Dictionary
    
        For j = 1 To 10
            dict(i).Add j, New Dictionary
        
            For k = 1 To 10
                dict(i)(j).Add k, New Dictionary
            Next
        Next
    Next
    
    dictErase dict
End Sub

Public Function dictErase(ByRef dict As Dictionary)
    Dim key As Variant
    
    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    For Each key In dict.Keys()
        If TypeOf dict(key) Is Dictionary Then
            dictErase dict(key)
        End If
    Next
    
    dict.RemoveAll
    Set dict = Nothing
End Function


This also did not work.
It seems that this issue isn’t confined to dictionaries alone. In the 64-bit version of VBA, memory for out-of-scope variables doesn’t appear to be released properly, or at least behaves differently compared to the 32-bit version.
Not working version: Microsoft® Excel® für Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2408 Build 16.0.17928.20114) 64 Bit
Working version: Microsoft® Excel® 2019 MSO (16.0.10413.20020) 32-Bit

On my Microsoft Excel 365 MSO (Version 2402 Build 16.0.17328.20550) 64-bit, the memory is realeased correctly every single time. I presume you are using the Scripting.Dictionary. Can you please try and see if you have the same issue using VBA-FastDictionary? It's a drop-in replacement and all you need to do is to import the Dictionary.cls class from the latest release and re-run your tests

Yes, I am using Scripting.Dictionary. Although VBA-FastDictionary uses significantly less memory (about 10 times less), the memory still isn’t released properly.
Even if I reset the application in the VB Editor, the memory remains occupied. I have to close Excel entirely for the memory to be released.
If it’s working fine on your end, perhaps the issue lies with my Office installation. I am using VBA Version 1141.

I am inclined to think that the issue is indeed with your software or possibly operating system. I just tested on 2 different computers, one on x32 and one on x64 both on Windows. No issue. Then tested on Mac (with FastDict) and again no issue. Have you tried to disable any existing add-ins? You can try Excel safe mode and see what happens

Thank you for your efforts. I have confirmed that no add-ins are enabled. The issue persists even when running Excel in safe mode. I have tested this on multiple PCs running both Windows 10 and Windows 11.

I'm convinced that it is a problem with the garbage collector.  I'm just working with array and my execution time is nearly doubling at times.  It may be happening when I'm stepping through code and then stopping execution. :-(

@TinMan There is no garbage collector in VBA. You probably meant it figuratively. Objects are deallocated when reference count reaches 0 and arrays+strings get deallocated when they get out of scope.

@Alex You can force compilation of code when opening the host workbook. See this. That ForceVBALoadFromSource registry key has been a life saver for me.

Thanks @CristianBuse for the clarification.  VBA does not have a GC is correct.  I really don't understand the difference between a GC freeing up memory and VBA freeing up memory when objects have no references and variables fall out of scope.  Anyway, I added code to my post that make the registry change that you recommended.  I hope it work for the OP and myself.  Thanks!

@CristianBuse I added the registry key, but the behavior didn’t change. I’ll ask my IT department to set up a clean PC with Office 365 only to test if the problem persists.

@TinMan My take is, a GC is freeing up memory at some later point, asynchronously, while VBA cleans everything synchronously. By async, I mean that the GC regularly scans the heap and deallocates memory not is use - however, in reality if does it both sync and async with the latter using some sophisticated algorithms. By sync in VBA, I mean that every time that IUnknown::Release is called (by setting object to Nothing or by existing scope) a check is made against the RefCount and if 0, memory is deallocated by the implementation of IUnknown before it even returns.

For BSTRs and SAFEARRAYs it happens when the stack frame is removed because each variable that lost scope is being deallocated on the spot. This still happens syncronously as VBA is single threaded and code runs sequentially, even though we can't step through some of it that runs behind the scenes.

Thanks again for your clarifications @CristianBuse.

Today, I installed Version 2409 (Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO, Version 2409 Build 16.0.18025.20030, 64-bit). With this update, memory is now being released properly.

I have recently been running into some memory issues myself not related to Dictionaries.  I've also had to set Application.ScreenUpdating = True at time (this has been do automatically for as long as I remember).  Hopefully, there will be a patch coming out soon.
Version: 16.0
Build: 18025
Architecture: 64-bit

Consider using MZ Tools Clean Project feature when you encounter weird behaviors.
MZ Tools Documents


I add this per Cristian Buse's comment
Sub AddRegistryEntry()
    Dim RegPath As String
    RegPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\Excel\Options\"
    
    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        On Error Resume Next
        .RegWrite RegPath & "ForceVBALoadFromSource", 1, "REG_DWORD"
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Successfully Updated"; "; RegPath"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Update Failed"; "; RegPath"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub


I am testing this with a new created workbook that contains only the posted code. ScreenUpdating is enabled.

@Alex You'll find that using the Clean Project feature will dramatically reduce the file size at times.  I brought MZ Tools 15 years ago and it is awesome.  But I don't think that it will fix your issue.  It looks like your version was updated on 9/10/2024, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date.  Do you know if it started happening after the last update?

Unfortunately, adding the registry key didn’t result in any improvement.

Thanks for adding the registry code. I always had crashes with big VBA code bases over the years, but zero crashes after I added this registry key. And this worked for my whole department.
